# Data ingestion from Spring boot application to splunk stops intermittently

Tags: spring-boot, splunk

I have a Spring boot application where I have configured log4j to use Http event collector.

The data ingestion is successfully done but the ingestion stops intermittently and again resumes, there is no definite pattern for resuming the ingesion

There is no failure logs in the tomcat as well.

Below are the configuration in log4j2-spring.xml :

```
<SplunkHttp
name="splunkhttp"
host="dummy"
source="source1"
url="https://http-yyy-xxxx.splunkcloud.com"
token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
index="ssssssss"
sourcetype="log4j"
disableCertificateValidation="true" >
<PatternLayout
pattern="%m" />
</SplunkHttp>


<Loggers>

</Logger>
<Logger name="com.some.service" level="debug" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="splunkhttp" />
</Logger>

</Loggers>
```

The following are the dependency in pom.xml :

```
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>splunk-artifactory</id>
<name>Splunk Releases</name>
<url>https://splunk.jfrog.io/splunk/ext-releases-local</url>
</repository>
</repositories>



<repositories>
<repository>
<id>splunk-artifactory</id>
<name>Splunk Releases</name>
<url>https://splunk.jfrog.io/splunk/ext-releases-local</url>
</repository>
```